# Click event of img tag inside clickable div tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a clickable `<div>`, in which I am adding `<img>` tags using jQuery.
All the `<img>` tags have the same `id`.
I want to click on the inserted image and handle the event for that element, but  I get the `<div>`'s event handler, instead.
I have tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` both on the `<div>` and added images, but it is not working.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#container").click(function (e) {
      debugger;
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

      var img = $('<img>');
      img.css('top', y);
      img.css('left', x);
      img.attr('id', 'marking');

      var selectedItem = $('#markerItem').val();
      if (selectedItem == 'b') {
          img.attr('src', 'broken.png');
      }
      else if (selectedItem == 'd') {
          img.attr('src', 'damage.png');
      }
      else if (selectedItem == 's') {
          img.attr('src', 'scratch.png');
      }
      else if (selectedItem === null || selectedItem === undefined || selectedItem === "") {
          img.attr('src', 'damage.png');
      }
      img.appendTo('#container');
  }),

  $("#marking").click(function (e) {
      debugger;
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $('img[id$="marking"]').remove();
  })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <img src="" height="475" width="600" alt="Image preview..." id="img1">
</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: every time I click on the container, a tiny image is inserted on runtime. how to have unique and trackable id then? apart from 'random' no gen function.

Comment: Why do you think you need id's? wouldn't classes be enough?

Comment: i've added the id as selector for the individual tiny images that are inserted inside the container div

Comment: But again, why id instead of class?